# Explanation for the following grammar written in ANTLR 4

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

I have a sample grammar written in ANTLR 4

```
query : select from ';' !? EOF!
```

I have understood

```
query : select from ';'
```

how it works

What does `!? EOF!` means in the grammar and how it works?

Comment: EOF means End Of File, if that is also what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exclamation marks is used in ANTLR v3 grammars to denote that a certain node should be omitted from the generated AST. Since ANTLR v4 does not have AST's, this construct is no longer used.

In both v3 and v4, the `?` denotes that a rule (lexer or parser) is optional and `EOF` means the end-of-file constant.

To summarize `';'!?` means: optionally match a `';'` and exclude it from the AST. And `EOF!` means: match the end-of-file and exclude this token from the AST.

So, the v3 parser rule:

```
query : select from ';'!? EOF!
```

should look like this in a v4 grammar:

```
query : select from ';'? EOF
```

Comment: If '?' is optional, then it should execute the query without ';'. Am I right? For example: If I execute the query, ('SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1') I am getting an error. I am getting result only when I insert ';' at the end of the query ('SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1;'). And the explanation for '?' I have read is ? which means that the symbol (or group of symbols in parenthesis) to the left of the operator is optional (it can appear zero or one times). So the definitions say that it can appear even zero times. In that case, if my above query is not having ';' i should get the result. right?

Comment: then why I am not getting the result if my query is not having ';'

Comment: @user2085189, I explained what the characters mean (so I consider this question to be answered). If you get error messages, I suggest you open a new question and **exactly** explain what the error message is and how you're running your test(s).